# How to use extended precision cmath functions by preference

Tags: c++, c

My question is this:  is there a way to always use the extended precision versions of mathematical functions - such as sqrt, exp, &c - without using an explicit cast when providing a single or double precision argument?

For example I want this functionality, without the hassle of the casting:

```
float x=15.0;
float answer;

answer=sqrt((long double)x);
```

This comes in the context of scientific computing, where many iterations of a loop containing such functions is required.  Even though at the end of the process I only require single precision, the floating point errors that result during each iteration can sum to something significant after a few thousand iterations.  Thanks.

Comment: The `sqrt()` function takes a `double` argument; the `sqrtl()` function takes a `long double` argument.

Comment: I should have specified that I am using C++ libraries, so the functions are overloaded as MSalters says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In C**

If you `#include <math.h>`, which declares such function as returning a `double` and accepting `double` arguments, the compiler will do the cast for you implicitily.

```
#include <math.h>

/* ... */

int x = sqrtl(sqrt(sqrtf(42)));
/* 1                     ^^    implicit cast of int to float          */
/* 2               ^^^^^^^^^   implicit cast of float to double       */
/* 3          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  implicit cast of double to long double */
/* 4    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ implicit cast of long double to int    */
```

Comment: True in C, not in C++ where they're overloaded.

Comment: By including cmath in C++ you also gain access to the expl, sinl, cosl, sqrtl versions of mathematical functions - thanks pmg.

Answer (score 2):

Cast to  long double before the loop and at the end cast result back to single precision?